# How to extract only date from Google Sheets cell

Tags: regex, date, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

I'm trying to extract only the date from this cell which says: `Current day (1 Nov 2019)`
Using:

```
=regexextract(concatenate(FullReport!B5),".*Current day(.*)")
```

Can't seem to figure out how to remove the brackets `( )` which I believe is causing it to not register in google sheets as an actual date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to extract:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "\((.+)\)")
```

[image: 0]

while true date would be:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(JOIN("/", 
 IFERROR(REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "\((\d+) (.+) (\d+)")*1, 
   MONTH(REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "\((\d+) (.+) (\d+)")&1))))
```

[image: 0]

or just:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(A1, "\((.+)\)")*1
```

Comment: While this works, it's switching the month and day for the real date.
Edit: Actually I think it's just not recognizing it as a real date even after changing number format for the cell.

Comment: not sure what do you mean. see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jBD4I.png

Comment: I have another cell that compares the date to this one, which is not registering this as the actual date.
```=IFERROR(IF(G$148 = Settings!$B$26,ArrayFormula(INDEX(FullReport!$D:$D,SMALL(IF("BEVERAGE Total:"=FullReport!$A:$A,ROW(FullReport!$A:$A)),1))),""),0)```

Comment: Unfortunately I tried all 3 of those but still having the same issue.
I appreciate your help.

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16huMKzeqbg3gho5klvRj91878H1ZARIs4F9RVRwE9M0/edit?usp=sharing
Week 41-44!G154

Comment: try: `=REGEXEXTRACT(FullReport!B5, "\((.+)\)")*1=F83`

Comment: For date comparison, it may help to convert to value. =value(REGEXEXTRACT(FullReport!B5, "\((.+)\)")). Using value() in the formula in cell G154 also seems to return the expected value.

Answer (score 0):

I tested with this formula and it works fine:

```
=regexextract(concatenate(FullReport!B5),"\(([A-Za-z0-9\ ]+)\)")
```

Comment: This returns ```Current day``` instead of the actual date for me.